# Load in external .html file with jQuery

Tags: javascript, ajax, jquery, tabs

I'm trying to create a website with tabbed browsing and have followed a tutorial to make this. But the problem is that the code I'm currently is using doesent work as expected.

- HTML-code:
  http://pastebin.com/CG146NS3
- CSS-code: http://pastebin.com/4VCuAwJm
- JavaScript: http://pastebin.com/sZhhQs6v

The tutorial I followed: http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/how-to-load-in-and-animate-content-with-jquery/

**The problem:**
When I click one of the tabs the #content goes away with a slideUp and .load loads the content but it doesent place the content in #content.

Comment: Is your external file on the same webserver?

Comment: can you post your `random1.html` too?

Comment: @justkt, yes. The external file is being loaded if you check with Firebug.

Comment: @ifaour, random1.html contains "<h1>Hello</h1><p>Hello</p>"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. You have some duplicate `#ids`.
2. Remember when you do:

   ```
   var toLoad = $(this).attr('href')+' #content';
   // other execution
   function loadContent() {
      $('#content').load(toLoad,function(){
      $('#content').slideDown('normal');
   });
   ```

you are actually loading a page fragment `#content` into `#content` in your page. So you end up with this:

```
<div id='content'>
   <div id='content'>Random Data</div>
</div>
```

Comment: removed the "'+ #content'" and it all works now. Thanks alot!

Answer (score 0):

Okay, based on your comment..Just make sure that you *actually* have a DIv with ID `#content` in your random html files.